# Batch file moved files to non existant folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am not an experienced windows user (go easy on me).

I was asked to create a simple batch file, which moved a group of files into a folder, using the Move method. This folder was called '1' (after a specific date). However, in my batch file, I mistakenly named it '01'. Instead of causing an error, the files were compressed, and moved into a new file in the path location, named '01'. It has no file type, and I am not sure how to expand it to see my original files again. I have tried converting it into .rar and .zip, but I fear this is me clutching at straws.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit:

Here is the original code, used for the file...

```
for /f %%f in ('dir/b \\folder1\folder2\Archive') do (

MOVE "\\folder1\folder2\Archive\%%f" "\\folder1\folder2\Archive\2011\11\01\")
```

Comment: Which version of Windows?  Any chance you can provide your batch file - or at least the exact (mistaken) move command you used?

Comment: Thank you. I am running windows 7. I have updated my question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the files one by one, instead of all at once, I guess (because that wouldn't have been possible otherwise).

The file `01` contains the contents of the *last* file you moved. Essentially if the target of a `move` operation is a file or doesn't exist, you're doing a rename. All files moved the same way into the same file are lost.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used a for /f loop. So I have no way of recovering them?

Comment: Try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but this is really not a SO question.

Comment: @Joey: You are right. The OP don't move a GROUP of files, but each file one by one. There is no way to recover the files except the last one: `ren 01 thelastfile.ext`

Comment: Thanks for your help, alas it seems I must concede that the files are lost, i begrudgingly accept your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (due to the likelihood of lost data), Joey's answer is probably correct.

If I try doing something like `move *`, I get an error back:  "Cannot move multiple files to a single file."

The other possibility is described here:  https://superuser.com/questions/111825/any-command-line-or-batch-cmd-to-concatenate-multiple-files

Basically, while not possible with "move" alone (due to the above warning) - maybe by an off-chance, you used the copy command, and then deleted the files after they were copied?  (An inefficient move?)  If so, then it's possible that the contents of your `01` file are the contents of all the individual files merged (concatenated) together.  In this case, it should still be possible to recover the data, assuming you can find the end-of-file locations for each file.

Since in either case, this didn't result in any sort of proper compression, it isn't a .zip file, and associated compression tools won't be of much assistance here.